# Send return line using get and jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get, newline

I am looking for a way to send a `<textarea>` value, using the jQuery `$.ajax()` function.

I have this code in a JavaScript function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php?answ=" + $('#answer').val(),
});
```

where `#answer` is the textarea, sadly, this text is a GET text, and its ignore new lines (`\n`)

What can I do?

Is it a good idea replace `\n` (newline character) with `<br />` (breakline tag) before sending GET data? and then replacing `<br />` with `\n` in the target code (test.php)?

Comment: would you further explain how you're going to apply the data? why would want a <br> as a next for? the data is raw data that's going to be used or stored somewhere. next time you pull it, then you should worry about new lines.

Comment: That's correct, the newline character is there, you just cannot see it.

Comment: I am storing it in a database, it's works fine if i send this data using POST, but it's not working using GET, it's ignore every newline character.

Comment: Why can't you use POST?